# How to use regex in Swift to capture string between colons

Tags: swift, regex, swift4

Have some string of any length returned from the backend as `"junkasdojf :text:"`

How would I use reg expression to return a clean string as `":text:"`(colons must be included)

Preferably a swifty way to handle this. Have not used regex before but I read that it is the only way to solve this besides doing nasty splits and reconstruction.

This is what I have so far but not sure how to progress

```
let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: ":[a-z]:", options: .caseInsensitive)
```

Comment: The issue is that `":[a-z]:"` is looking for only ONE characters included between two colons and that is a lowercase letter from a to z. When I see `:text:`, that's four letters. That's why it's not working.

Comment: gotcha thanks @Larme

Comment: @FarhanFarooqui So, you are not  interested in where `:...:` appears, right? I had an impression you only wanted to get `:....:` after `junkasdojf`, hence [posted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55683853/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rmaddy's answer would be a preferable way for a simple, non-repeating task and AamirR's answer seems to be the right solution when you do not mind using `NSString` in a Swift code.

But the basic usage of `NSRegularExpression` with Swift `String` would be something like this:

```
let str = "junkasdojf :text:"

//You can use `try!` when you are sure your pattern is valid.
//And do not miss `+` after `[a-z]`.
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: ":[a-z]+:", options: .caseInsensitive)
//Use `str.utf16.count`, not `str.count`.
if let match = regex.firstMatch(in: str, range: NSRange(0..<str.utf16.count)) {
    //Use `Range.init(_:in:)` to convert `NSRange` to `Range<String.Index>`.
    let range = Range(match.range, in: str)!
    //When you can accept `Substring`, `String.init(_:)` is not needed.
    let matchingStr = String(str[range])
    print(matchingStr) //->:text:
} else {
    print("*NO mathes*")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It would be simpler to use `range(of:options:)`.

```
let someStr = "junkasdojf :text:"
if let substrRange = someStr.range(of: ":[a-zA-Z]+:", options: .regularExpression) {
    print("Match = \(someStr[substrRange])")
} else {
    print("No match")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following will match multiple occurrences

```
// \w matches any word character such as [a-zA-Z0-9_]
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: ":\\w+:")

let nsString: NSString = "junkasdojf :text: flkasdj junkasdojf :two:"
let matches = regex.matches(in: nsString as String, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length))
for match in matches {
    print(nsString.substring(with: match.range))
}
```

Comment: No need for the `.caseInsensitive` option here since `\w` finds any word character regardless of case.

Answer (score 1):

A more generic way is to use a capturing group:

```
let pattern = "junkasdojf\\s*(:[^:]*:)"
```

Sample Swift code:

```
let str = "Some string here, junkasdojf :text: and more here"
let pattern = "junkasdojf\\s*(:[^:]*:)"
do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
    if let match = regex.firstMatch(in: str, range: NSRange(str.startIndex..., in: str)) {
        let result = str[Range(match.range(at: 1), in: str)!]
        print(String(result))
    }
} catch { print(error) }
```

See [**the regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/N8d7sx/1).

Here, `junkasdojf` matches the substring that is the left-hand context for the string you need, `\s*` matches 0+ whitespaces and `(:[^:]*:)` captures into Group 1 a colon, any 0+ chars other than `:` and then a `:`.

Alternatively, if the number of whitespaces between `junkasdojf` and `:` cannot exceed some maximum threshold, you may use use a *constrained-width lookbehind* based solution:

```
let s = "Some string here, junkasdojf :text: and more here"
if let rng = s.range(of: ":(?<=junkasdojf\\s{0,1000}:)[^:]*:", options: .regularExpression) {
    print(s[rng])
}
```

This won't work at regex101 as it does not support ICU regex flavor, but this assumes there can be no more than 1000 spaces between `junkasdojf` and the next `:`. `:(?<=junkasdojf\\s{0,1000}:)[^:]*:` matches a `:`, then makes sure there is `junkasdojf` followed with 0 to 1000 whitespaces and a `:` (this is necessary to anchor to the first `:`) and then `[^:]*` matches zero or more chars other than `:` and then a `:` matches `:`.

Also, if you are interested in the shortest regex possible, but less efficient solution, you may regex-replace the input string using

```
let s = "Some string here, junkasdojf :text: and more here"
let result = s.replacingOccurrences(of: "(?s).*junkasdojf\\s*(:[^:]*:).*", with: "$1", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
print(result)
```

Output: `:text:`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lvTdjF/3)

**Details**

- `(?s)` - a modifier that allows `.` to match line break chars
- `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible
- `junkasdojf` - a substring
- `\\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(:[^:]*:)` - Capturing group 1 (`$1`): colon, 0 or more chars other than `:`, colon
- `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible

Comment: This seems really inefficient. 1. It needs to match the entire string, most of which doesn't need to be matched. 2. It requires that part of the string that the OP doesn't care about must be hardcoded into the RE (the `junkasdojf` part). 3. It does relatively expensive and unnecessary string replacement. That's a lot of extra work and requirements just to find a substring.

Comment: @rmaddy I did not say it is efficient. It also depends on what kind of input is fed to the regex. If the strings are not large, the solution will be much simpler and clearer than all other here and still appropriate. It is the only solution posted here that checks the presence of `junkasdojf` in the input. Besides, if the performance is an issue, I can add another solution that does the same job and still checks for context.